# How to create 360 image viewer?

Tags: android, 3d, 360-degrees

I want to impliement something like this https://ggnome.com/object2vr/examples/vespa

They use series of images to create illusion of 3d model. How to implement this in android? Do someone knows appropriate libraries?

Comment: hope [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-android-cardboard-360-video-viewer--cms-27689) will help..

Comment: how did you acheive this later? I have implemented something like this but Im running OOM when there are lots of images. Say 36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vr from google SDK. https://developers.google.com/vr/android/